# Redis set command succeeds but database not changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

This one is driving me nuts.  I am deactivating a user by altering their session store in Redis.  First I find the key, alter the value, and set the new value.  The replies all indicate that the commands are succeeding but redis-cli shows no change to that key.

```
// Update the Redis session

var client = redis.createClient();

var keys = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.keys('*', function(err, reply) {
        if(err) reject(err);
        resolve(reply);
    });
});

var data = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    keys.forEach(function(key) {

        resolve(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            client.get(key, function(err, reply) {
                if(err) reject(err);

                var session = JSON.parse(reply);
                if(session.userId == userId) {
                    session.authenticated = false;
                    return resolve({key: key, value: JSON.stringify(session)});
                }
            });
        }));


    });

});

var reply = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    client.set(data.key, data.value, function(err, reply) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(reply);
    });

});
console.log(keys);
console.log(data);
console.log(reply);
```

Even though I set the authenticated property to false for that key, it still shows as true from redis-cli.  The log from the console and the reply shows that the command was successful but it isn't.  Any ideas?

This is what I get back from redis-cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get sess:_xArN7ShiZRjyxbv_5xuh0FhTU6orlX5
"{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"loginFailed\":false,\"authenticated\":true,\"userId\":1"}"
```

Comment: Please add the command you are using in the `redis-cli`.

Comment: I am using get keyname and it shows the stringified JSON and the authenticated value is still true.  I actually did a get after the set completed and it showed false but STILL the cli showed true.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the specific command you use and an example of what the result looks like (the part of the json that matters).  It will make it easier for us to see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I added the response I get from redis-cli.  Basically I am attempting to log out a particular user after that user has been deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was testing this on myself which doesn't work because the value that I set was being overwritten by the session middleware.

Also the promises were executing in parallel rather than sequentially so nesting callbacks made more sense in this case and solved that part of the issue.

Hoping this helps someone else.